# When using the inline tag editor in Teams, the word 'Tags' is duplicated

Tags: bug, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams, inline-tag-editor

When using the inline tag editor in Stack Overflow for Teams, the word 'Tags' is duplicated:

[image]

Comment: *At most one tags is required* ...

Comment: There's also similar behavior for the "People asked" element in Teams. If you click the "Add People" button (or the "Edit" button, if others on the Team have already been pinged on the question in this way), then an inline editor appears for just that element, and it displays "Ask team members" just below the existing "People asked" heading. (But at least in that case, it's not just showing you the same word twice in a row :P)